# Why can't Windows detect phones, even when the USB driver is installed?

Tags: adb, samsung, usb-debugging, usb-connection-mode

After reinstalling Windows, both two of my Samsung phones cannot be recognized by the OS. In Device Manager it shows this:

[image]

I tried to install:

- [Samsung USB Driver for Windows](https://developer.samsung.com/mobile/android-usb-driver.html)
- [Android Studio and SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio)
- [Samsung Smart Switch](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/app/smart-switch/)

And activated USB Debugging mode, but none of this still work.

Despite of that Odin can still detect it:

[image]

Using `adb devices -l` yields this result:

```
List of devices attached
420039c4de446300       device product:j1x3gxx model:SM_J120H device:j1x3g
```

or

```
List of devices attached
504bc61e               device product:j2y18ltedx model:SM_J250F device:j2y18lte
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the reason for this is because you are using the N version of Windows. Microsoft explicitly states that [some features are effected](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4057437/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-n-april-2018) in this version. Users have reported that [the wpdmtp.inf file is missing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/wpdmtpinf-file-is-missing/c085262b-a2c9-4fac-a3a5-80aea6df4799), and this is why the MTP protocol has error.

You can download [Media Feature Pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3145500/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions) to fix this.

And why does this need to happen?
From [What Is an “N” or “KN” Edition of Windows?](https://www.howtogeek.com/322112/what-is-an-n-or-kn-edition-of-windows/)

> These editions of Windows exist entirely for legal reasons. In 2004, the European Commission found Microsoft had violated European antitrust law, abusing its monopoly in the market to hurt competing video and audio applications. The EU fined Microsoft €500 million and required Microsoft to offer a version of Windows without Windows Media Player. Consumers and PC manufacturers can choose this version of Windows and install their preferred multimedia applications without Windows Media Player also being present. It’s not the only version of Windows offered in the European Union—it’s just an option that has to be available. This is why the “N” editions are only available in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

Often you first have to install the driver and then connect the device. If you do it the other way around the driver will not be applied correctly. Delete the shown MTP entry and disconnect + reconnect your phone. Also run Windows update with enabled "updates for all Microsoft products".

Regarding adb your new PC is unknown to the device (because the stored adb RSA key has been lost because of the new installation) and therefore it denies adb access (device unauthorized).
You first have to unlock the device (enter pin/password/pattern) and then accept the dialog that asks you if your device is allowed to connect via adb.

And that Odin works at the same time is because Odin uses different drivers. From the perspective of your computer you have 3 USB devices, one for MTP, one for adb and one for Odin. Check it out by selecting the MTP device and then changing the device manager "View" -> "Devices by connection".

You will see al the USB device endpoints from your device.

Comment: Thanks. The ADB now can detect the phones. What do you mean by "delete the shown MTP entry"? Disable or uninstall the device? The OS is up-to-date

Comment: @Ooker Select the MTP entry and press "del" key on your keyboard. This seems to named "uninstall" in the context of the device manager.

Comment: I delete it and reconnect the phone but the new MTP entry still has error