# What is the differences between the three USB drivers: MTP, Odin, ADB?

Tags: adb, usb-connection-mode, odin, usb-drivers, mtp

In [Why can't Windows detect phones, even when the USB driver is installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232322/94084), @Robert says:

> And that Odin works at the same time is because Odin uses different drivers. From the perspective of your computer you have 3 USB devices, one for MTP, one for adb and one for Odin.

One can confirm this by going to `Device Manager` → `View` → `Devices by connection`:

[image]

What are the differences between them? Are there any other kind of driver? And which one is the [Samsung USB Driver for Windows](https://developer.samsung.com/mobile/android-usb-driver.html)?

Comment: On your picture, the 1st is for transferring files (MTP: Media Transfer Protocol), the 2nd is for comms via adb (also fastboot), the 3rd to use your phone as a modem to connect the PC to internet via your phone.

Comment: Each USB device requires it's own special driver. As I wrote from the perspective of Windows these are three more or less independent USB devices. And for what they are used is pretty clear by their name.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio that would be a great answer. If you expand it to be an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: sounds like [Win 10 MTP bug](https://www.google.com/search?q=mtp+usb+device+twrp) sometimes you can fix by switching between MTP <-> PTP modes until Win will re-detect device (and maybe re-install drivers)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio adb / fastboot are different modes with different drivers too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your picture, the 1st is for transferring files (MTP: Media Transfer Protocol), the 2nd is for comms via adb (also fastboot), the 3rd to use your phone as a modem to connect the PC to internet via your phone.